# How to make an asynctask wait till the activity called from the asynctask is closed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an asynctask from which I open an activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, pdActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent );
```

The activity contains done and cancel buttons. When clicked on the buttons Im closing the activity and want to know which button is clicked (Done/Cancel) in asynctask. 
Can anyone help me in achieving this??

Comment: do you know how thread works?

Comment: yes of course.. but asynctask is not waiting till the activity is closed

Comment: the way asycTask works, i believe that you can't do this...

Comment: can u please suggest me and other way?? Can I start another asynctask for activity..??

Comment: please explain what you actually want to do with asynTask. just starting an activity doesn't seem to be a big deal. it is unnecessary and waste of resources, isn't it? so tell me what makes you implement such thing..

Comment: It's TCP communication, where the asynctask is an android service that receives a pdf file from TCP client and I have to display it in activity for signing, providing done/cancel buttons. If user click on done, I have return the pdf bytes and if user click on cancel I have return emptybyte array from the asynctask to tcpclient.

Comment: alright. if i get you exactly then, you should first create a service for your tcp connection and from their you can create activity. now implement that service with Broadcast receiver and when you are done with activity, just broadcast the message, so your service will be notified.

hope this will solve your implementation problem.